# Are USB unplug events logged in Windows 7? (When was my mouse stolen?)

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse, event-log

I know this sounds kind of ridiculous, but someone stole my mouse from my cubicle.. I came to work in the morning and was about to give my mouse a little shove to wake up the monitor, but it wasn't there!

I'm trying to figure out when this happened. I'm running Windows 7 and it's a USB mouse. I checked the event logs, but there doesn't seem to be any logs that might tell me what I'm looking for.

Is there any place where USB unplug events are logged?

Comment: My event log is called a security camera.

Comment: Do you turn off, or standby, your computer at night?

Comment: @jscott - Nope, always on so that I can remote in if needed

Comment: I generally find missing mice in the dryer.

Comment: Interesting questions. As far as your co-workers: totally lame. But I'd like to know the answer to this one.

Comment: Set a trap, buy a hidden camera and a nicer mouse to temp the thief again.

Comment: I love this question, would love to see it answered...

Comment: was the culprit ever caught?

Comment: @AndrewHeath - Yes, I got a confession out of the intern I was mentoring :) And actually he didn't steal the mouse--he just hid it behind my workstation tower as a prank. It was still plugged in, so USB unplug logs wouldn't have helped anyway.

Comment: Related question: 2014-12-08, [*Logging when someone connects or removes a USB device to/from a Windows machine*](https://superuser.com/questions/849950/logging-when-someone-connects-or-removes-a-usb-device-to-from-a-windows-machine)

Comment: Might be of help in the future.....https://www.eventtracker.com/blog/2014/june/tracking-removable-storage-with-the-windows-security-log/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a log of them unfortunately - those events are lost forever. I've always wanted a `dmesg` equivalent on Windows.

With Windows XP and earlier, you can use `winmsd` to produce a system configuration output, but in later versions it's been replaced with `msinfo32` (GUI application that I'm not so sure about parsing the output of).

Both of those only give you point-in-time information though, so for mouse-theft detective work you'd need to be regularly logging the output of `winmsd` to a file. I must admit I'd personally go with the webcam suggestion in the future.

Comment: But is it "possible" for a Windows program to do it? Or is the functionality just not available in Windows (so programs do not have the capability to do so)?

Comment: Actually, there is a log file for this. It's called [*Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode-Operational.evtx*](http://dfstream.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-windows-7-event-log-and-usb-device.html) but it's disabled by default on Win10.

Answer (score 11):

It might be too late now, but there ARE a couple pieces of software that will do exactly that. The easiest one to use being [USBLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html)

Other options, not so friendly, are the [Windows USB Storage Parser](https://www.tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=13) or Microsoft's USBView (UVCView on Win7), that ships with the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

If you really want to get your hands dirty, open RegEdit and look for the following entries:

> **Description**: List of Installed USB devices, both connected and
>   unconnected **Location**:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB **Why you care**: It
>   can be useful to know what USB devices have be connected to a box, and
>   even the vendor and serial number of the device in some cases. Think
>   someone copied the data to a thumbdrive? This may help you trace down
>   what thumbdrive. Think how useful it can be to help tie something a
>   user physical possesses to a box.
>
> **Description**: List of installed USB storage devices **Location**:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR **Why you care**:
>   Much like the installed USB devices entry, but just for USB storage.
>   Think someone copied the data to a thumbdrive? This may help you trace
>   down what thumbdrive. CleanAfterMe scrubs
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB but not USBSTOR
>   when I tested last.

Comment: Monitoring those keys with Procmon.exe from SysInternals did exactly what I needed.