# Determine source of device disconnected sound on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I've had this issue with my PC for a while. I randomly hear the classic device disconnected tone, but I can never find the source of it. Usually more frequent around the time I lock/unlock Windows.

I tried using Nirsoft's USBDeview to try to see if some USB device is acting up, but it doesn't log events, I just see blips sometimes, but can't really see what might be the actual issue.

Are there logging tools for this sort of thing, or maybe I can filter Event Viewer by some event Id?

Comment: See if it's a USB hub or camera, which I've found frequently dis/reconnect, by temporarily unplugging a device, one at a time, for a few days.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik advice is good.. but also see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/849950/logging-when-someone-connects-or-removes-a-usb-device-to-from-a-windows-machine) to show you how to see EVENTS as to hardware connect/disconnect.